# Тэги <html> и <body>: какому следует присваивать стили визуального оформления всей страницы?

Tags: html, css

В некоторых примерах я видел, что тегу `<html>` устанавливают параметры `margin`, `padding` и другие, а сам всегда начинал присвоение стилей с `<body>`. Вопрос такой: какая разница *с точки зрения визуального оформления* (`color`, `background-color`, `padding`, `margin` и т. д.) между `<body>` и `<html>`, или какому тегу из этих двух тэгов можно присваивать стили, а какому - не стоит?

Comment: Т.к. вся разметка страницы, обычно, содержится в <body>, то стоит присваивать стили именно ему.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вообще, любому из них - в зависимости от того, что удобнее.

Но есть несколько особенностей.

## rem

Единица измерения `rem` - это размер шрифта `html` (или `:root`), но не `body`:

```css
html { font-size: 100px; }
section { font-size: 20px; } /* drop inheritance */
div { font-size: 1rem; } /* 100px */
```

```html
<section><div>123</div></section>
```

```css
body { font-size: 100px; }
section { font-size: 20px; } /* drop inheritance */
div { font-size: 1rem; } /* default */
```

```html
<section><div>123</div></section>
```

## Фон

Если задан фон только у `body`, то он распространяется на `html`. Но если у обоих, то он будет разный. По умолчанию `body` не занимает весь экран - добавим границ:

```css
body {
  background: silver;
  border: 4px solid red;
}
```

```html
Just some text
```

```css
html {
  background: white; /* not taken from body now */
}

body {
  background: silver;
  border: 4px solid red;
}
```

```html
Just some text
```

## Отступы

По умолчанию `body` имеет отступы:

```css
html {
  margin: 0; /* doesn't work */
}

body {
  border: 4px solid red;
}
```

```html
Just some text
```

```css
body {
  border: 4px solid red;
  margin: 0; /* reset here, not on html */
}
```

```html
Just some text
```

## Ну и ещё один финт

Элементы из `head` не обязаны быть невидимыми.

```js
(  document.head.querySelector('title')
|| document.head.appendChild(document.createElement('title'))
).textContent = "Just a title";
```

```css
head, title {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
Page content goes here...
```

Comment: Было бы вообще прекрасно дополнить примеры ссылками на соответствующие разделы стандарта :)

Comment: @andreymal, согласен... Но для этого их надо найти...

Answer (score 2):

**Если коротко**, то смело присваивайте стили и к `<html>` и `<body>` в зависимости от целей вёрстки.

---

**Если подробнее:**

1. `<html>` это такой же контейнер, как и любой другой  и т.п., только основной, поэтому к нему так же применяются все те правила, как и для других подобных элементов.
2. Аналогично с `<body>`, который также является контейнером, в котором содержится основная вёрстка, а же он в свою очередь расположен в `<html>`.
3. Т.е. по сути на конструкцию:

   ```
   <html>
     <body>
     </body>
   </html>
   ```

   нужно смотреть как на:

   ```
   <div>
     <div>
     </div>
   </div>
   ```

А так как, почти у каждого элемента на странице, включая `<html>` и `<body>` есть свой стиль по умолчанию (стиль браузера), который нам скорее всего нужно будет изменить, то мы просто берём и изменяём его, как любой другой, для того чтобы добиться необходимого визуального эффекта. Например:

```
--------------------------
| HTML                  _|______ Чтобы повлиять на внутренний отступ <html>,
|    ----------------  | |       необходимо будет задать свойство padding
|    | BODY         |<-->|       непосредственно для самого <html>, а иначе 
|    ----------------    |       к этому свойству будет не подобраться.
|                        |       
--------------------------
```